# SWT Text Icon Search option

Tags: java, swt

In RCP application I am using SWT Text as follows -

`Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.SEARCH | SWT.ICON_CANCEL | SWT.ICON_SEARCH);`

Inside the `Text` there is an option to get a icon of Search and Cancel. I am getting this
icon on Ubuntu Linux, whereas on Windows 7 this icon in not visible. Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: Something useful here: http://blog.dominikschadow.de/?p=245

Comment: @Baz- Thanks for reminding me :) Hv accepted ur answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows does not support this feature.

There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293230) with some suggestions how to implement it yourself.